# MySQL slave replication - slave behind master - how to speed up?

Tags: mysql, replication, slave

I have master - slave replication and we have a lot of records inserting into the master to the point where the slave update is not fast enough. We've innodb and maybe the replication on slave is single threaded. I wonder if there's anything we can do on the db side instead of making changes on coding or table structure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation, and what helped us was enabling those two parameters on slave:

> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
>
> sync_binlog=0

They are making slave instance less durable, but way faster. Hope it will help.